# How to scroll to a component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make sure that when there's a click on a router link within the `<app-navbar>` component, the browser will scroll down to the router outlet ?

This is what my `app.component.html` looks like at the moment:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="row h-100">
    <app-header class="h-100 overflow-auto col-md-12  col-lg-5"></app-header>
    <div id="main" class="h-100 overflow-auto col-md-12 col-lg-7">
      <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `<app-navbar>`contains router-links and the `<app-header>`takes up 100% of the height on mobile. So I want to make sure that whenever a user clicks on a link in the navbar, the page scrolls down to the newly loaded component under the `<app-header>`

I had a look at this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll but couldn't manage to make it scroll (I suppose because I was trying to scroll to an element of a different component).

Just when I was about to edit this message I found this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-scroll but same thing, I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Start with [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: @ChrisW. not a great suggestion since the browser support isnt very good.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @SmokeyDawson All browsers support it, you just don't get the nifty options like `smooth` scroll in a couple of them....

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of research, here is a solution that works :

1. Make sure the `<app-module>`gets the click event in the `<app-navbar>`

Exemple of a link in app-navbar.html :

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="bio" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="scrollToMain()" >Bio</a>
```

Exemple of app-navbar.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  @Output() scroll: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

scrollToMain() {
    this.scroll.emit(true);
  }
}
```

2. Catching the event in app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <app-navbar  (scroll)="onScroll('#main')"></app-navbar>
  <div class="row h-100">
    <app-header class="h-100 overflow-auto col-md-12  col-lg-5"></app-header>
    <div id="main" [@routeAnimations]="o && o.activatedRouteData && o.activatedRouteData['animation']"
      class="h-100 overflow-auto col-md-12 col-lg-7">
      <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Acting on the event in app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { PageScrollService } from 'ngx-page-scroll-core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private pageScrollService: PageScrollService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
  }

  onScroll(target) {
    this.pageScrollService.scroll({
      document: this.document,
      scrollTarget: target,
    })
  }
}
```

It could work as well with scrollIntoView but I used the ngx-page-scroll to make things smother : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll.

Hope it helps someone :)